# How to change color to adjust theme setting in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

Simply want to set `Foreground` color of a `TextBlock` to `LightGreen` in dark mode , set to `DarkGreen` in light mode. There is a theme setting in my app. I want the color adjust both system setting and app setting.

I tried this when page loaded:

```cs
var isDark = ThemeSelectorService.Theme == ElementTheme.Dark;
if(ThemeSelectorService.Theme == ElementTheme.Default)
{
   isDark = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark;
}
PriceText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(isDark ? Colors.LightGreen : Colors.DarkGreen);
```

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="PriceText" Text="This is a Text"/>
```

but when I change the system setting, the color will not change until reload to this page, how to make it happen?

Comment: Could you please tell me what ThemeSelectorService.Theme represents, does it represent the PriceText.RequestTheme property? It is better if you could provide us with the code about how you change the theme in code-behind.

Comment: `ThemeSelectorService.Theme` represent `RequestedTheme` for `Window.Current.Content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When system color changes, the page loaded method will not be called. You could use [UISettings.ColorValuesChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.colorvalueschanged?view=winrt-19041) to monitor the changes of system color.

> when I change the system setting, the color will not change until reload to this page

If you change the color of your app by changing the value of [FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.requestedtheme?view=winrt-19041) which can override the app-level `RequestedTheme`, you need to change the value of the `FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme` property to `ElementTheme.Default` to let the `FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme` use the [Application.RequestedTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme?view=winrt-19041) without reloading the page.

Please check the following code to let the color adjust system setting:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ……
    uiSettings.ColorValuesChanged += UiSettings_ColorValuesChanged;
}

private async void UiSettings_ColorValuesChanged(UISettings sender, object args)
{
    var isDark=false;
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        //Change the RequestedTheme of elements to ElementTheme.Default
        // if you have changed some elements' RequestedTheme property
        RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default;
        ThemeSelectorService.Theme = ElementTheme.Default;

        isDark = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark;
        PriceText.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(isDark ? Colors.Green : Colors.Red);
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. But still wondering is there a easier way to create a themebrush just like `ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush`.

Comment: You could use [ThemeResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references#theme-resources-and-theme-dictionaries) to change the foreground of TextBlock controls when the theme changes. Note to change the RequestedTheme of elements to ElementTheme.Default if you have changed some elements' RequestedTheme property in UISettings.ColorValuesChanged event handler.

Comment: For example,

           `<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries><ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="foregroundBrush" Color="Red"/>              </ResourceDictionary> <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="foregroundBrush" Color="Green"/>                </ResourceDictionary></ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

            ……

<TextBlock Foreground="{ThemeResource foregroundBrush}" >Hello world</TextBlock>`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want !

Answer (score 2):

Answer from YanGu

Step 1: add ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries to ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PriceBrush" Color="DarkGreen"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PriceBrush" Color="LightGreen"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Step 2: use the SolidColorBrush for your usercontrol

```xml
<TextBlock Text="This is a text" Foreground="{ThemeResource PriceBrush}"/>
```

This is pretty easy but cannot be found in other questions.

Comment: Precisely what I needed. Thanks!